How to return unique count of URL param value in Datadog
In a Datadog dashboard it has been reuqest to build out a chart that is just a count of the unique occurrences of a param, lets just call it an ID, that exist in our URLS.
As an example
/path/path/1111111

Where 1111111 is the unique ID value. However there are other URLS that may exist like
/path/path/1111111/path

Given those two URLS it would still only be counted as one.  I need to get a count of all those ID values (in my example 1111111) but not the unique URL hits using them.
closest I have gotten in Datadog is a count of the Unique URLS, but again, that counts URLs like the two above each as unique and I only want to get a count of the unique occurrences of the D values regardless of the URL.
Let's say in the Datadog Dashboard this value is @id for the sake of the property.
